# what is the purpose of ServletException in java & when it will be thrown?

Tags: java, servlets

I am not able to find the purpose of ServletException from the java API documents,
While overriding service method we write throws ServletException, but when it will be thrown this checked exception?

Answer (score 2):

```
 If there is any error with status code either 404 ( Not Found) or 403 ( Forbidden ) then the ServletException may be thrown
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be various reasons of you getting this Exception. I could recall one that I personally faced is when server was unable to allocate/load a servlet instance, due to not having enough server memory. In stack strace it shown as "Error allocating a servlet instance".